# Steam keeps crashing. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: steam

This is the output of LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam

> 

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled   
> automatically Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) Installing breakpad exception handler for   
> appid(steam)/version(1.0) [2016-05-22 07:22:11] Startup - updater   
> built Mar 29 2016 17:40:06 Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly,  
> scheduling immediate update check [2016-05-22 07:22:11] Checking for  
> update on startup [2016-05-22 07:22:11] Checking for available   
> updates... [2016-05-22 07:22:12] Download complete. [2016-05-22   
> 07:22:12] uninstalled manifest found in   
> /home/lightning/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1). 
> [2016-05-22 07:22:12] Found pending update [2016-05-22 07:22:12]   
> Installing update... [2016-05-22 07:22:12] Extracting package...   
> [2016-05-22 07:22:35] Installing update... [2016-05-22 07:22:44]   
> BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to create directory ./steam/cached   
> [2016-05-22 07:22:44] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to process ./steam  
> [2016-05-22 07:22:44] Failed to apply update, reverting...   
> [2016-05-22 07:22:44] Verifying installation... [2016-05-22 07:22:44] 
> Performing checksum verification of executable files [2016-05-22   
> 07:22:44] Unable to read and verify install manifest   
> /home/lightning/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
> [2016-05-22 07:22:44] Verification complete [2016-05-22 07:22:44]   
> Downloading update... [2016-05-22 07:22:44] Checking for available   
> updates... [2016-05-22 07:22:44] Download complete. [2016-05-22   
> 07:22:44] Extracting package... [2016-05-22 07:23:08] Installing   
> update... [2016-05-22 07:23:16] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to create 
> directory ./steam/cached [2016-05-22 07:23:16] BCommitUpdatedFiles:   
> failed to process ./steam [2016-05-22 07:23:16] Failed to apply   
> update, reverting... [2016-05-22 07:23:21] Shutdown
```

Sorry for the mess. This is my first time on a forum

---

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?  The error causing your problem is `BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to create directory ./steam/cached` but when I search that error I only come up with Arch and Gentoo related problems.  If you are using Ubuntu, how did you install Steam?  You are getting what looks like permission related problems, you should not get that it you installed it via the .deb on the Steam website or with `apt-get install steam`

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed Steam using sudo apt-get install -y steam. I got it working now by using 'LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam' in terminal